# How to pass touch events from child view to parent?

Tags: android, touch, parent, drag

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop functionality in an Android application. The drag part is done, the one thing left is to figure out where the dragged view will be dropped? On which view, to be more precise. 
Here's the onTouch function of my dragged view:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // Is the event inside of this view?
  if (!mRegion.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
   return false;
  }

  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
   ...
   System.out.println("**** IMAGE DRAG STARTED!");
   return true;
  } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        ...
   this.invalidate();
   return true;   
  } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
   System.out.println("**** ICON DRAG ENDED!");
   return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 }
```

All motion events are handled except the ACTION_UP (the moment when the view is released). The question is how should I make this event to be called in the parent (pass it to the parent's onTouch handler), so I can find out where it was dropped. I have implemented onTouch handling in the parent but no event is caught.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)

Comment: My pleasure.  Have a look at GestureDetector and VelocityTracker.  You may find them useful.